# How to use an asynchronous function that must be completed first in a react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to make an async function in react class component which must be completed first.

I don't want to use a lifecycle like componentDidMount, so I used top-level await like this:

```
let data;

(async () => {
  data = await asyncRequest();
})();

class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {data}</h1>;
  }
}
```

However, in the code above, even though top-level await is used, if a certain amount of time passes, the render proceeds before the asynchronous operation ends.

how can i solve this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a lifecycle method? They're there to solve problems like this.

Comment: The async function and render function are running synchronously. Only code inside of the async function will be run asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be the async function you've created. You've got to use a then block with it

```
let data;

(async () => {
  data = await asyncRequest();
  return data;
})();

class Test extends React.Component {
  render().then(function(res, err) {
    return <h1>Hello, {data}</h1>;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to initialize a boolean variable that you can call isLoading with a default value of true. Once the async function finishes you change isLoading to false.

In your render function you can write something like this:

```js
if(isLoading) {
  return <h1>Loading...</h1>
} else {
  return <h1>Hello, {data}</h1>;
}
```

I usually use this method when I can use a lifecycle but I don't see why this couldn't work